# Getting :-1: error: [Makefile.Debug:71: debug/Tappian_Ball.exe] Error 1 when trying to use LIBS

Tags: c++, qt

I am getting :-1: error: [Makefile.Debug:71: debug/Tappian_Ball.exe] Error 1 when trying to use `LIBS +=  -framework <KF5Solid>`
I want to add KDE Solid to my project and these 2 lines are actually responsible for that

`QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+= -F/$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/KF5Solid/`

`LIBS +=  -framework <KF5Solid>`
Maybe the problem is in KF5Solid directory, I downloaded source code from [here](https://invent.kde.org/frameworks/solid), unpacked it to the source code folder

Qt 5.14.2
Windows 10
MinGW 32-bit

Comment: The actual error message should be above the -1 error and it likely should give you some additional information.

Comment: You were right, The message is "The specified file cannot be found.", but which file? If <KF5Solid>, then how to specify KF5Solid framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I had to compile Solid framework and add it as usual library.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).